# Toggle Grid Display (What am I missing?)

Tags: javascript, css, grid, toggle, display

Wrote some code to Toggle whether a Grid of Images is Displayed or not. it is a 6x8 grid, so i did not include the 72 div elements here. When the Image Grid is not showing, a text list is visible. Hence the change in Button Text. Having trouble Finding any Errors.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#photo-index {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 0px;
  background-color: #4f6b6f;
}
#toggle-button {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.75);
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>    
<script>
function toggleDisplay() {
    var pi = document.getElementById('photo-index');
    var displaySetting = pi.style.display;
    var toggle-button = document.getElementById('toggle-button');
    var showTaxonomy = 'Show Taxonomy';
    var showImages = 'Show Images';
    if (displaySetting == 'none') {
    pi.style.display = 'grid';
    toggle-button.innerHTML = showImages;
    }
    else {
    pi.style.display = 'none';
    toggle-button.innerHTML = showTaxonomy;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div onclick="toggleDisplay()" id="toggle-button">Show Taxonomy</div>
<div id="photo-index">Large Grid of Stuff</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a error in the variable declaration `toggle-button` is not a valid variable in JavaScript, so use `toggle_button`. The JavaScript variable do not allow hyphen in variable declaration as it is considered as arithmetic operator.

```js
function toggleDisplay() {
    var pi = document.getElementById('photo-index');
    var displaySetting = pi.style.display;
    var toggle_button = document.getElementById('toggle-button');
    var showTaxonomy = 'Show Taxonomy';
    var showImages = 'Show Images';
    if (displaySetting == 'none') {
    pi.style.display = 'grid';
      toggle_button.innerHTML = showImages;
    }
    else {
      pi.style.display = 'none';
      toggle_button.innerHTML = showTaxonomy;
    }
}
```

```css
#photo-index {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 0px;
  background-color: #4f6b6f;
}
#toggle-button {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.75);
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="toggleDisplay()" id="toggle-button">Show Taxonomy</div>
<div id="photo-index">Large Grid of Stuff</div>
```

Comment: New to StackOverflow. Thank you, Sir.

As a note: Also had to switch the Text-Toggle (i had them backwards)